# GridGain slim version

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Ran security scans and noted that it reports more vulnerabilities in gridgain-community-8.8.33.zip and very few in the gridgain/community:8.8.33-openjdk11-slim docker image.

Is there a way to get the slim version of gridgain-community-8.8.33.zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can get the same effect by deleting any dependencies you don't use. (The slim image has fewer libraries in `libs/optional` but otherwise it is identical to the full one.)